# Why my iOS tableview do not work

Tags: ios5

I am learning iOS programming and I had a problem with tableview.
By tapping a cell in tableview, I want my program change to another view,here is my code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    testViewController* controller=[[testViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"testViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"gyf.jpg"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

the view controlled by testViewController is super simple. There is only a image view in it.
But after I tap the cell, there was only a blank view on the screen without any image.
In debugging, after `controller.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"gyf.jpg"];`,I found controller.imageview is nil.
**Please tell me where is the problem and why this phenomenon happen,thank you very much**
I use Xcode 4.3.3 and run the program on iPhone 5.1 simulator

Answer (score 0):

(This answer assumes that your `testViewController` displays OK and is just not getting the image you want.)

When you create a new controller and push it, it's view hierarchy isn't loaded until it executes `viewDidLoad:`.  You're trying to update its `imageView` before that happens.  Try adding a `UIImage` property to `testViewController`, setting that property instead in this code, and then updating the `imageView` once all the views are valid in the new controller.